# Bootstrap 3 modal creates scrollbar when opened

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use Bootstrap for the first time and am having an issue with modal dialogs. Using the example code on [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/), when the modal is opened a scrollbar appears, which also shifts the content on the page to the left.

Code:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/WqRBP/

A lot of sites I'm looking at use Bootstrap and they don't have this issue, so is there some sort of easy fix for the problem?

EDIT: The scrollbar appears in Chrome and IE, I haven't tested in other browsers.

Here's what I'm seeing in JSFIDDLE:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont notice any scrollbar when I launch the modal in your jsfiddle.

Comment: @Yogesh It appears in Chrome, not sure about other browsers..

Comment: @Yogesh I added pictures of what I'm seeing. I'm using Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m.

Comment: @Nate What do you want it to be? Should the text be displayed inside the modal?

Comment: @LVarayut I just don't want an unnecessary scrollbar to appear. I've seen lots of websites with Bootstrap modals like this, and none of them have a scrollbar appear when the modal is opened. I don't want the scrollbar to appear because it makes the page "jump" when the modal is opened and closed.

Comment: This might help. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem occurred because `Twitter Bootstrap` always shift the page 15px to the left when a modal is opened. You can solve this by moving the page back to the right - `margin-right: -15px`. This can be done by using events `show.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.modal` provided by `Bootstrap's modal`.

```
$('#myModal').bind('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $("html").css("margin-right", "0px");
});
$('#myModal').bind('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $("html").css("margin-right", "-15px");
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lvarayut/WqRBP/3/)

---

**FYI:**

`show.bs.modal`: This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.

`hidden.bs.modal`: This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

[Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why they shift the page to the left and show the scrollbar, even when not needed?

Comment: @LVarayut: Great answer.

Answer (score 34):

LVarayut's answer sent me in the right direction and what I ended up using is this:

```
body.modal-open, .modal-open .navbar-fixed-top, .modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.modal {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: I replaced `margin-right: 0` to `overflow-y: auto;` and it works.

Comment: @tom have you tested it on pages with scrollbars? For me, Billy Chan's change results in there being two scrollbars.

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution:

```
.modal {
 margin-right: -15px;
}`
```

and add this also

```
body.modal-open {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 4):

It is so simple, just add to your css:

```
body.modal-open{overflow:hidden!important;}

/*Optional:*/
.modal-open, .modal{padding-right:0!important}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution

```
#myModal{
    overflow:hidden;
}
body {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

With this,you will force your page to have a scroll bar.

Comment: If you have a fullscreen modal with a scrollbar, you get 2 scrollbars.

Answer (score 2):

This [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855) is solved in Bootstrap version 3.2.0, which was released on 23/06/2014.

Thanks to @roadsunknown for the link (in the question comments).

Comment: I've updated to 3.2.0 and I'm still experiencing the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: The fix adds `style="padding-right: 16px;"` to the body, so the content shouldn't be shifted anymore. Fixed navbars are still shifted...
Try to check that you have `.modal-open { overflow-y:auto }` for correct scroll bar appearance during opened modal window.

Comment: I got it to work for 3.2.x with `padding-right:0` like this: http://bootply.com/VxeV1fiQSk

Answer (score 1):

This work for me. It should work fine

```
body.modal-open { 
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following css :

```
.modal{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

I already solved my problem by this way.

Answer (score 0):

this did a trick for me

```
$('html').bind('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   console.log('hidden');
   $("html").css("margin-right", "0px");
});

$('html').bind('hide.bs.modal', function () {
   console.log('hiding');
   $("html").css("margin-right", "-15px");
});

$('html').bind('show.bs.modal', function () {
   console.log('shown');
   $("html").css("margin-right", "-15px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can overwrite bootstrap main css using your own css cause sometime may effect other. so this is simple code which work

```
body.modal-open .modal {
    margin-right: -15px !important;
}

body.modal-open {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

if you want to change main bootstrap css then update this

```
body.modal-open, .modal-open .navbar-fixed-top, .modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
  .modal-open {
         overflow-y: auto
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were my own styles that caused the problem:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

You may change `html` to `body` so there is only one scrollbar:

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Its mainly due to the CDN used ...Remove the CDN https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" from your page and the problem is solved..I had done it.