# Bootstrap modal moves to top on panel click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the question that I asked before but didn't get a problem-solving response. What's happening right now is that I am opening modal on the click of a panel. The modal opens with no problem but the problem occurs when I scroll to bottom and click a panel which moves to body scroll to top.

Here is the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/SHc5P/show) with the code.

Here is the panel code I am using:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body" onclick="loadArticle('Metrico Release Date Announced', 'http://www.ign.com/articles/2014/07/16/metrico-release-date-announced')" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
        <h4>Metrico Release Date Announced</h4>
        <div class="news-item-background-image"></div>
        <br>
        <div class="article-info">
            <p class="text-muted pull-left">
                <img src="http://s1.wp.com/wp-content/themes/vip/techcrunch-2013/assets/images/favicon.ico" width="16px" height="16px">TechCrunch-1 hour ago</p><a href="#"><p class="text-muted pull-right category">Category</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <p>Metrico will be released on August 5 in the US exclusively on PS Vita, according to an announcement on the&nbsp;PlayStation Blog. Digital Dreams also announced that Palmbomen, a Dutch synth composer who has been featured in games like GTA V worked with the studio to create the soundtrack for Metrico.</p>
    </div>
    <!--/span-->
</div>
```

In my CSS, I have added this:

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: visible !important;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And I know that this is the reason why is this happening because `position:fixed` with no top value I guess moves it top. If not this, then what should I do to fix the problem.

P.S the css above fixes the extra scrollbar issue that is also happening. So keep that in mind while answering. Just a tip! :)

Comment: Where is the "To Top" button? Can't find it in the fiddle!

Comment: I can only reproduce the "scroll to top" in your fiddle when I click the word `Category` which is in every `.article-info` in your panels. And this simply happens because it is wrapped in an `a` tag with an empty anchor link `<a href="#"><p class="text-muted pull-right category">Category</p></a>`. Remove this and there should be no more scrolling to top.

Comment: @Sebsemillia the issue still persists.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui what did you change? Any updated fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

So after a heck of time, figuring out the way to fix it, this is my workaround (inspired by the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829332/bootstrap-3-modal-creates-scrollbar-when-opened#_=_)):

```
$('.bs-example-modal-lg').bind('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("html").css("overflow", "visible");
});
$('.bs-example-modal-lg').bind('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

The first bind regulates the event of modal when it hides and enables the scroll of whole page while the second one regulates the event when it shows up and disables the scroll of whole page.

Simple. :)