# Bootstrap: Header moves when modal opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap framework and having some trouble with my header and modals.
The header on my page is fixed and when a modal opens it moves a few pixels to the right and moves back again when the modal closes.

An example is shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/7400/

I would like it to not move at all. I know this is caused by the scrollbar which is why the container in the fiddle is set to 2000px. Any ideas to how I can solve this problem?

The code is the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

   <header>
    <nav id="menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
    <a href="#" class="menu-toggle dl-trigger"><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i></a>
      <ul class="dl-menu">
        <li>
         <a href="#home" class="scroll"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#profile" class="scroll"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
    margin-top:100px;
}

.modal-content {
     height:500px;   
}

header {
        width: 150px;
        margin:auto;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.90);
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

Comment: With a really quick look, I can see that when you open a modal, the body gets a modal-open class which has CSS that gives it overflow:hidden. Removing this CSS seems to clear up your problem though I am not sure why, just yet.

Comment: I have also noticed this however it does not affect the rest of the content on my page. Only the fixed header.

Comment: On your fiddle, I am noticing the button which is outside the header move too.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but there's a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829332/bootstrap-3-modal-creates-scrollbar-when-opened) that you may find interesting. Also, notice [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and [here](http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) that when the modal is opened the `body` gets a `padding-right:16px` to compensate for the disappearance of the scrollbar; otherwise these sites would have the same problem as your fiddle. I'm not sure why the bootstrap javascript running in your fiddle does not insert this padding as well.

Comment: Btw, in your fiddle you are using CSS from Bootstrap 3.3.0 and javascript from Bootstrap 2.1.0

Comment: Sounds like you might be describing https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14040

Comment: Yeah, I have tried the solutions mentioned in the link but unfortunatly none of them solved my problem. I guess they are target previous versions of bootstrap.

Comment: Updating bootstrap solved it

Answer (score 7):

Simple Fix

```
.modal-open {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me and did not screw any other view on my website.

Answer (score 5):

**Updated Answer**

This should do the trick:

```
.modal-open[style] {
   padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/gqrpf1vw/5/)

Hope this helps!!!

Incase you're wondering why, the "modal-open" class was applying a inline style of "padding-right: 15px" so just overwrite the CSS and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: That partly fixes the problem. When the page has a scroll bar (the content is larger than the screen), there is added a second scroll bar which forces the content behind the modal to shift left :(

Comment: I appreciate the help very much :) We are getting closer however with this implementation I am not able to scroll the modal only the background. It should be reversed so only the modal is scrollable.

Comment: Looks like the folks at Bootstrap changed the way this is handled. Rather than using a "padding-right" (inline-style) they are now applying the same class "modal-open" but using "overflow: hidden;". I recently changed this to "overflow: visible !important" and re-solved the issue. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
.modal {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-open {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: This also adds another scrollbar and it is the background instead of the modal which is scrolling :(

Answer (score 0):

This happens becouse when the modal show up, body receives "overflow:hidden". This cause the scroll bars to hide, the distance refers to the scrollbar width.

To test it, use:

```
body{
    overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

The problem to "fix" this is, scrollbars vary a little from browser to browser, so or you make the scrollbars always visible, or you add some padding-right with jquery (around 18px);

Answer (score 0):

It's just because your body loses scrollbar and your body width expands on behalf of the scrollbars width. Either add overflow:scroll; to the body css properties or use some custom scroll bar js plugin - there are scrollbars that dont share window width with body element.

Answer (score 0):

When the modal opens, everything from the page are moving. Also, a class `.modal-open` is adding up in the body tag. So, I tried to add a `padding-right: 15px;` to `.modal-open`. The body is no longer moving except to `header`. So I've also added a `padding-right: 15px` to the `.modal-open header` and everything works fine now.

CSS should be added:

```css
.modal-open {
  padding: right: 15px;
}
.modal-open header {
  padding: right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

none work but changing the bootstrap itself from

```
(this.$body.css("padding-right")||0,10)
```

to

```
(this.$body.css("padding-right")||0,0)
```

Took me about an hour to find it and change

Answer (score 0):

You can move your header when the model opens, in your CSS file:

```
.modal-open header { padding-right: 17px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is already reported in bootstrap's repo, and I have found this solution working for me.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14040

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        var oldSSB = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.setScrollbar;
        $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.setScrollbar = function () {
            oldSSB.apply(this);
            if(this.bodyIsOverflowing && this.scrollbarWidth) {
                $('.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom').css('padding-right', this.scrollbarWidth);
            }       
        }
        var oldRSB = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.resetScrollbar;
        $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.resetScrollbar = function () {
            oldRSB.apply(this);
            $('.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom').css('padding-right', '');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-top,
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    padding-right: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your header class "is-fixed":

```
<header class="is-fixed">
```

This class has no efect to your design. But when the modal is open, Bootstrap will add to every element with this class somethink like that:

```
style="padding-right: 17px;"
```

where 17px is the actual width od the scrollbar. Bootstrap do the same with the body element.

```
<body> //close modal
<body class="modal-open" style="padding-right: 17px;"> //open modal
```