# Bootstrap 4 modal pop up header login stretch to the right when click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

My bootstrap 4 login pop up on the header stretch all the way to the right when clicked.

[My header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bSVT.png)

[The header when I clicked the login pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AomK9.png)

Here's my link code:

```
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-info px-4 mt-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal1">Login</a>
        </li>
```

Here's my modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="loginModal1">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title">Modal Login Form</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Sign in</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi @jerico, do you want to stretch your nav bar `home`, `service` and all link to right, when modal button is clicked. right?

Comment: Hello @yash, when I open a modal (click on login the top menu) the background move and stretch all the way to the right. How can I avoid that ?

Comment: but i cannot see in screenshot as you are saying. look at that it is not moving. just due to modal popup, you are not able to see home and service, else no change.

Comment: it stretch to the way up to right and overflow the scroll bar..

Comment: I added answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: heres my code @yash https://jsfiddle.net/9hLkp8z6/7/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap: Header moves when modal opens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819725/bootstrap-header-moves-when-modal-opens)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it by adding this in my scss code..

```
 .modal-open {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    }

  .modal-scrollbar-measure {  
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's modal automatically adds the class `modal-open` to the body when a modal dialog is shown and removes it when the dialog is hidden. it's functionality provided by bootstrap.

This makes the scrollbar disappear due to bootstrap css :

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can override that by specifying

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

in your own css. This will probably solve your problem.

===============================

if you need more detail knowledge on this, as i mentioned in comments, go to [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14040)

As said over [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14040#progressive-timeline-item-container), this works for you :

```
.modal-open {
overflow-y: auto !important;
padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.modal-scrollbar-measure {

overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I added the .modal-open on my scss codes.. the header actually works but it still moved when the login button cliked https://jsfiddle.net/9hLkp8z6/11/

Comment: it's moving left, because, when modal dialog open, it will hide scrolling from back page. Fore more info look at [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14040)

Comment: Hi @jerico, if it helpful to solve your problem, you can upvote or mark it as expected.