# Entire HTML page shifted to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm setting up a simple website, and for some reason, the entire page is shifted to the right by about 15 pixels - the `<html>` and `<body>` tags, too. This causes a horizontal scroll-bar to appear.

The `html` and `body` elements do not have any margin or padding defined (as is confirmed by Firefox 'layout' pane). I also don't have any negative margins or paddings.

The site is too complex to create a fiddle, it can be seen [here](http://test.chelem.co.il)

I'm using Bootstrap.

Comment: How come so many downvotes without any comment nor appearing reason?

Comment: I have a theory. I'll try to confirm it next time I have a question to ask.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you didn't even try to isolate the problem.

Comment: I haven't *succeeded* in isolating the problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s just because of bootstrap styles:

```css
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Clear margins for row.

Comment: I had a `row` div without a surrounding `container` div! Thanks!

Comment: isqua is correct, supporting link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829332/bootstrap-3-modal-creates-scrollbar-when-opened

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken:

Your div class="row" has a left and right margin of 15px. This often causes the

Comment: Row has negative left and right margins, which are offset by `container` or `container-fluid`'s margins. I forgot the surrounding container.